# Count number of records per week giving massive number of NULL

Tags: php, mysql, date, group-by

I have tried about 10 different variations of queries similar to the following:

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR( dateline ) AS weekno, COUNT( 1 ) AS posts
FROM post
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR( dateline )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The resulting data is always a few results and about 600,000 "NULL" like so:

```
weekno  posts
NULL    591843
1   57
2   42
3   25
4   44
5   9
6   38
7   15
8   41
9   10
10  130
11  77
12  69
13  36
14  25
15  25
16  24
17  44
18  42
19  14
20  49
21  70
22  41
23  40
24  57
25  40
26  31
```

Here is the table structure for `dateline`:

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default     Extra
7   dateline    int(10)         UNSIGNED    No  0
```

All of the rows have a value in dateline.

I need to get some sort of group by week working because ultimately I want to graph out the post activity with and without a specified forum section. I don't know why I'm getting all of these `NULL` results.

Comment: why is your date an int?

Comment: That is how vBulletin has it structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your date is stored in `unixtime` integer format, assuming that it is `unixtime` try [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline)) AS weekno, COUNT( 1 ) AS posts
FROM post
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline))
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

To return weeks from different year try this

```
SELECT 
FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline, '%Y') Year,
WEEKOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline)) AS weekno, COUNT( 1 ) AS posts
FROM post
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline, '%Y'), WEEKOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline))
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b350/5)

Comment: Thank you. I tried solutions using FROM_UNIXTIME but I guess they had other errors in them.

Comment: I didn't mean to hit enter. Now, this works if I limit to the past year, but how would I do this for multiple years? Additionally, I have added the line: `DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline), INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline)) DAY) AS 'WeekStart'`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Year, WEEKOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateline)) AS weekno, DATE_ADD(FRO' at line 1

Comment: Hmm, at first glance the query looks right. It has data separated by week for the entire life of the database. But when I graph the data it behaves other than expected. When limited to 1 year it performs correctly, only showing a difference in the past 2 months http://i.imgur.com/l2lx572.png

But when I graph it without restraining to a year it gives strange data as seen here http://i.imgur.com/WTZpgmM.png

In any case I don't really *need* to graph more than a year, so I'll mark your answer as correct, but it doesn't work for >1 year.